# Can content by search webpart be used instead of search result webpart

Tags: 2013

can we use content by search web part instead of search result web part if yes , how can we connect it with the search box web part as pass the search query to it!!

Comment: come on guys ? please help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Content By Search WebPart. It just takes query text from the Url and displays the results in it. Nothing to configure.